# Changing window.open popup location on second monitor

Tags: javascript, window.open, multiple-monitors

I have a popup window set to open in a specific location on screen. On the primary monitor (monitor 1), the popup window will open in the location I list (slightly left and up from center screen), however when I try opening the popup on monitor 2 (to the left of the primary monitor) the window defaults to the upper right corner of monitor 2 and will not change opening location if I adjust the "top" and "left" parameters.

Here is the code:

```
    function callMotorInformation() {
        var tempVehicleID = document.getElementById('<%=vehicleIDHF.ClientID%>').value;
        var tempNumber = document.getElementById('<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').value;
        var url = "motordefault.aspx?WorkorderID=" + tempNumber + "&VehicleID=" + tempVehicleID;
        var retval = window.open(url, "Labor Diagnostics", "location=0,menubar=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,titlebar=0,top=100,left=200,width=830,height=630");
```

Comment: _"[...] the behavior is implementation-dependent, and web author should not rely on it."_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Position

Comment: evolutionxbox misrepresents what the actual remark is saying.
"IF ONLY ONE OF THEM IS SPECIFIED, the behavior is implementation-dependent, and web author should not rely on it."
So in this case it does not apply, since he is supplying both left and top values